# Googlemock: How to verify elements in an array in an object?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a small class:

```
struct Command
{
    uint8_t cmdId;
    uint8_t len;
    uint8_t payload[MAX_PAYLOAD];
};
```

And I want to verify only the first two elements of the payload using a googlemock expectation.  I can't use ElementsAreArray because that checks that the lengths of the payload and the expectation are the same.  So far I have an expectation that looks like this:

```
Command cmd;
cmd.cmdId = 0xD3;
cmd.len = 2;
cmd.payload[0] = 'm';
cmd.payload[1] = 'l';

EXPECT_CALL(mockQueue,
        sendFromIsr(Pointee(AllOf(
                Field(&Command::cmdId, Eq(0xD3)),
                Field(&Command::len, Eq(2)),
                //Field(&BirdCommand::payload, ElementsAreArray(cmd.payload, 2)) !<-- Doesn't work
        ))))
        .WillOnce(Return(true));
```

Any ideas?  The mock class looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MockQueue : public Queue<T>
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1_T(sendFromIsr, bool(T &item));
};
```

Comment: What is the signature of sendFromIsr method?

Comment: @VJo I have added the mock definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received this solution from Piotr Gorak via the googlemock mailing list, [discussion here](http://groups.google.com/group/googlemock/browse_thread/thread/487f1c44d601131f).

```
MATCHER_P2(CheckFirstTwo, first, second, "Checks the first two elements of an array")
{
    return arg[0] == first && arg[1] == second;
}
```

And in the test I verify like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockQueue, sendFromIsr(
        Pointee(AllOf(
            Field(&BirdCommand::cmdId, Eq(0xD3)),
            Field(&BirdCommand::len, Eq(2)),
            Field(&BirdCommand::payload, CheckFirstTwo('m', 'l'))
        ))
));
```

I like this solution the most because it does not require me to over-specify the test or zero initialize the data structure in my production code unnecessarily.

Comment: Why was this voted down?  It solves the problem exactly how I specified it.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with this :

```
EXPECT_CALL( mockQueue, sendFromIsr( Ref( cmd ) )
        .WillOnce( Return( true ) );
```

?

Since the Command is POD, it should work even if it copies the command (which it doesn't in this case).

---

**EDIT**

Since the Command is POD, you need to zero initialize it (or clear the memory occupied by such object when you create it. In your example :

```
Command cmd = Command();
```

Then your object will not be uninitialized and the comparison should not fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately that wont work because the whole message is not written in.  That means that the remainder of the payloads will differ (but that is ok since they are not valid).

Comment: @mikelong Maybe because your Command is POD, and like you declared variable `cmd` it might contain garbage. Try to zero initialize it, and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockQueue,
        sendFromIsr(Pointee(AllOf(
                Field(&Command::cmdId, Eq(0xD3)),
                Field(&Command::len, Eq(2)),
                Field(&Command::payload[0], Eq('m')),
                Field(&Command::payload[1], Eq('l'))
        ))))
        .WillOnce(Return(true));
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that doesn't compile.  g++ message is "error: object missing in reference to ‘Command::payload’"